# Entity is not persisted

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm implementing JPA in my application. 
This application already uses Spring, Hibernate SessionFactories(3), Wild Fly server with XA Datasource, and a JTA Transaction Manager.

In order to test JPA I set it on a simple Entity which is not linked with any other Entity.

Select and HQL query is ok but not save.
My problem is when I create or update this Entity, nor creation nor modification is effective and there is no error.

I wonder if problem is not on TransactionManager side.
I do **not** have **persistence.xml** file

The service :

```
@Service
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager")
public class UtilisateurServiceImpl implements UtilisateurService {

       @Autowired
       private UtilisateurDao utilisateurDAO;

       public UtilisateurServiceImpl() {
       }
...

public void creerUser() {
           utilisateurDAO.creerUser();
       }

}
```

The dao :

```
@Repository
public class UtilisateurDaoImpl implements UtilisateurDao {

       @PersistenceContext(unitName="habilitationPersistenceUnit") private EntityManager entityManager;     

       public UtilisateurDaoImpl() {

       }
...

       public void creerUser() {
           UtilisateurEntity utilisateur2 = new UtilisateurEntity();
        utilisateur2.setDateCreation(new Date());
        utilisateur2.setFax("");
        utilisateur2.setIdentifiant("Olivier");
        utilisateur2.setPassword("password");
        utilisateur2.setMail("");
        utilisateur2.setNom("Potonnier");
        utilisateur2.setNomAffichage("Olivier Potonnier");
        utilisateur2.setPrenom("Olivier");
        utilisateur2.setTelephone("");
        utilisateur2.setDateMAJ(new Date());
        //utilisateur2.setPk(40);
        try {
        entityManager.persist(utilisateur2);
        entityManager.flush();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//        try {
//         UtilisateurEntity entity = entityManager.find(UtilisateurEntity.class, 1);
//         entity.setPassword("password");
//         entityManager.merge(entity);
//        } catch(Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

       }
```

Entity :

```
@Entity @Table(name="UTILISATEUR")
public class UtilisateurEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3416450676331189345L;

    @Id @GenericGenerator(name="entityIdGenerator", strategy="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.dao.impl.PkGenerator", 
                          parameters={@Parameter(name=PkGenerator.TABLE, value="SEQUENCE"),
                                      @Parameter(name=PkGenerator.PK_COLUMN_NAME, value="ENTITE"),
                                      @Parameter(name=PkGenerator.PK_COLUMN_VALUE, value="UTILISATEUR"),
                                      @Parameter(name=PkGenerator.VALUE_COLUMN_NAME, value="NUMERO")
                          })
    @GeneratedValue(generator="entityIdGenerator")
    private Integer pk;

        @Column(name="NOM") private String nom;
        @Column(name="PRENOM") private String prenom;
        @Column(name="IDENTIFIANT") private String identifiant;
        @Column(name="PASSWORD") private String password;
        @Column(name="NOM_AFFICHAGE") private String nomAffichage;
        @Column(name="TELEPHONE") private String telephone;
        @Column(name="FAX") private String fax;
        @Column(name="MAIL") private String mail;
        @Column(name="DATE_CREATION") private Date dateCreation;

        @Column(name="DATE_MISE_A_JOUR") private Date dateMAJ;


        public Integer getPk() {
            return pk;
        }
        public void setPk(Integer pk) {
            this.pk = pk;
        }
    ....
    }
```

Datasource config

```
<!-- Data sources des differents schema -->
    <bean id="dataSourceReferentiel" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/DS_Referentiel" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceHabilitation" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/DS_Habilitation" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceSinistre" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/DS_Sinistre" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
```

Entity managers config

```
<bean id="referentielEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="referentielPersistenceUnit" />      
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceReferentiel" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com...entity.referentiel" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <!-- Privilégier les logs debug de org.hibernate.SQL -->
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="habilitationEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="habilitationPersistenceUnit" />      
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceHabilitation" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com...entity.habilitation" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <!-- Privilégier les logs debug de org.hibernate.SQL -->
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sinistreEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="sinistrePersistenceUnit" />      
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSinistre" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com...entity.sinistre" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <!-- Privilégier les logs debug de org.hibernate.SQL -->
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Could you post your hibernate configuration ?

Comment: Post also your spring configuration

Comment: I've updated the initial post and set my config. There is a particularity, I have no persistence.xml file may be pb is here

Comment: I have a feeling the `@Transactional` annotation you're using isn't setting up correct transaction to the database. For example how do transactionManager know it should start transaction in referentiel / habilitation / referentiel?

Comment: @Transactional is set with the JTA transactionManager set in my config. For the session factories it's correct. there is a difference between both. Session factories have "hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" property but not my entity managers

Comment: do you have any errors in your logs at all? have you added logging to ensure your methods are being called?

Comment: I have tested in debug mode, step.by step. Method is called, ... Persist. No error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had to define a persitence.xml, define entities and transaction lookup. With this (below) it works.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="referentielPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="habilitationPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.entity.habilitation.UtilisateurEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="sinistrePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add just 1 last thing on this topic. 
Because I'm using JTA transaction with XA datasource I must declare a peristence.xml file and set in the JTA lookup and declare all enties.

JTA brings lot of constraints but if you need it you have a sample here.
In most cases prefer not to use JTA, declarations & settings will be simpler.